# populate submitted email subject line with data from livecycle form text field

Tags: livecycle

I have a pdf form created in Livecycle it is set up with a submit button and will submit a pdf of the form via email.

NOW I want to have the subject line of the email come from on of the filled out fields in the form.  for example: client name field will populate the email subject line with whatever is typed into the client name field.

I'd also like to know how I can reduce the file size of the form it's 2mbs currently.

Can anyone help?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With the ready-to-use [Email submit button](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/designerHelp/000471.html#1584994) you can't dynamically set the subject.

However, you can create your own button to submit the form by email and use a script to dynamically set the subject and send the email:

- drag a regular button into your form,
- open the script editor for the `click` event ([more info](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/designerHelp/000738.html#1582009)),
- set the language to `JavaScript` and
- use a script like the following:

```js
// Replace with actual path to the field which contains the subject:
var subject = path.to.field.rawValue;

var myDoc = event.target;
try {
    myDoc.mailDoc({
        bUI: false,
        cTo: 'receiver@domain.com', // Replace with actual receiver mail address.
        cSubject: subject,
        cSubmitAs: "PDF"
    });
} catch (e) {
    // exception handling...
}
```

You can find more in-depth information here: http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/dynamically-setting-submit-e-mail-address. In this tutorial not the subject but the receiver mail address is set dynamically, but you can apply the same principle to any of the parameters of the `doc.mailDoc(...)` function.

Regarding your question on how to reduce the file size: either your form is veeery large or you have images with large file sizes embedded in the form. In the latter case search for ways to reduce the image file sizes. For example, check if you are using `.jpg` or `.gif` or `.png` files and *not* `.bmp` files (which are uncompressed and hence very large) or use images with a lower resolution (72 dpi is ok for screen display).

Comment: OK I think I get this BUT I want the subject needs to be info taken from one of the form fields.  Where the code reads cSubject: should I insert the name of the Text Field?  EX: cSubject: TextField6,      Thanks I'm going to give this a try.

Comment: This is very weird.  The article you referred me to is the exact article I found before I checked here to see if I got a reply.  Psych happeing perhaps! : ) @bassim

Comment: @shirleymarotta In the script editor, on the first line of the script where it says `var subject = path.to.field.rawValue;`, select the words `path.to.field`, hold the CTRL key and click on the field "TextField6" in your form. The path to the field is then being generated for you. The content of TextField6 is now stored in the variable `subject`. This variable is used in the call to `myDoc.mailDoc(...)` to set the parameter `cSubject`. This way the content of TextField6 ends up in the subject of your email. The article will also be helpful :)

Comment: That is very helpful. It's the little details that get missed.  I have more questions though:

Comment: @bassimThat is very helpful. It's the little details that get missed.  I have more questions though:  1. I need to either have the To: line of the email blank or filled in automatically from one of the form fields.(it's not always going to the same place) can this be done?  2: Can I have more than one form field go to the subject line?  You are being so helpful I really do appreciate this. Thanks!

Comment: @shirleymarotta Almost everything can be done, it's a question of resources :-) Please create another question for your problems, this is getting way out of the scope of the original question.